# Math.random is creating infinite numbers, rather than just one

Tags: javascript, math, random

What's wrong that's causing my randomizing code for num1 and num2 in my function question() (in a class Enemy) to repeat indefinitely? Below is the related code within question(), and it correctly generates two numbers between 0-30 and 0-15 respectively, but indefinitely.

```
    num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (31 - 0)) + 0;
    num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (16 - 0)) + 0;
    textSize(84);
    strokeWeight(1);
    fill('#1f7ac4')
    text(num1, 200, 170);
    text('x', 200, 270);
    text(num2, 200, 370); 
    text('= ???', 200, 470);
```

And below is the code that runs question(), based on simple co-ordinate collision detection between the player object and enemy1.

```
function draw() {
  background(220);
  image(BG,0,0,width,height); 
  player.show();
  enemy1.show();
  collision();
}

function collision() {
  if (player.x >= 555 && player.y < 90 && player.x <= 605){
    enemy1.question();
  }
```

The problem is that, when I move the two objects collide, and question() executes, these two lines of code with random `num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (31 - 0)) + 0; num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (16 - 0)) + 0;`
on repeat, rather than just once. How can I get it to only spit out one number for this collision, and then remove the enemy1 object?
Thank you.

Comment: Generate the random numbers in the class constructor, not the `question()` function, and save them as object properties.

Answer (score 0):

You're not changing the position of the enemy1 object or deleting it after or in your question() function. This means every time draw is called, then it detects the collision and calls question(). I'm also assuming that this happens because you're drawing this on the screen multiple times per second, due to a frame rate, under my assumption that this is some type of game loop.

You should code in the question() function or after it that your enemy is either deleted or moved to somewhere new on the screen (to basically "spawn" a new enemy without actually having to create one) after a collision is detected.

Comment: I've given the enemy a new position at the end of question(), so now it moves the enemy correctly after giving the question box. How can I get it to stop the player, and ask it for an input, and then move the enemy, if the answer is correct? I've tried using prompt(), but it asks for it before the numbers are shown on screen, despite being after the display in question().